# How to get file path in single argument while passing the data to MVC controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

In my ASP.Net MVC application I am trying to pass the three arguments to an action which is looking like below:

```
public ActionResult File(string hash, string eid, string filename)
```

till yesterday when invoking this action method I was having URL like below:

{ControllerName}/{ActionName}/{hash}/{eid}/{fileName}

for e.g.:
C1/A1/6CAE9919C0DDDDC49B5E6E6068E7B7A0/S_FR_EID_002/ITTTFileDB.pdf

I dont want to change the route pattern from "/" format to ? (conventional pattern)

Now the last parameter file name is coming with folder/directory name like below:

Folder1/TestFolder/File1.pdf

and it can be at any level in a folder, I want to get the "Folder1/TestFolder/File1.pdf" whole value inside fileName argument. So my new URL is looking like below:

C1/A1/6CAE9919C0DDDDC49B5E6E6068E7B7A0/S_FR_EID_002/Folder1/TestFolder/File1.pdf

My projects routes are being configured using url rewrite in web.config like below:

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="RewriteUserFriendlyURL1" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="^content/attachment/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Rewrite" url="content/attachment/file?hash={R:1}&amp;eid={R:2}&amp;filename={R:3}" logRewrittenUrl="true" />
    </rule>
    <rule name="RewriteUserFriendlyURL2" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="^content/attachment/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/^]+)$" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Rewrite" url="content/attachment/file?hash={R:1}&amp;eid={R:2}&amp;filename={R:3}" logRewrittenUrl="true" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use route with *

```
[Route("{hash}/{eid}/{*filename}")]
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult File(string hash, string eid, string filename) 
{
}

or 

routes.MapRoute(
    "Upload",
    "file/{hash}/{eid}/{*filename}",
     new { controller = "Upload", action = "File", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

Comment: Hi @cdev thanks for your reply, my routes are configured using urlrewrite rule in web.config so even if I change the attribute route like you suggested its not working.

Following are the ruleset from the web.confi, existing rule
<match url="^content/attachment/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$" />
Added a new rule like below: